# Virtualenv permission denied

Tags: bash, virtualenv, permission-denied, virtualenvwrapper

After a lot of struggle with virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper I decided to remove all virtualenvs and re-install the packages.

```
root> su myuser
myuser> sudo pip install virtualenv
myuser> sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

I proceeded to add this to my unix users .bashrc file.

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2.7
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

When I source .bashrc I get about 20 error lines ending with `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/.virtualenvs/premkproject'`. I'm running out of ideas...

I have done my homework and tried every suggested solution I could find. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Have you tried doing all of this without sudo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and it was due to .virtualenvs having owner and group root.  So the following would fix it (substituting ubuntu:ubuntu for your user and groups):

`cd ~
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu .virtualenvs/`

I used the recursive option as I had a problem installing a package with pip and that was due to a file lower down the hierarchy also having a permissions problem.

Answer (score 0):

You never explained in which SO are you working...So if you are in Mac OS X you can easily fix it by giving eXecute permissions.
I believe Linux may face the very same problem altought I myself never got this problem under Linux.
The 'magic words' are the following :

```
chmod 755 <your path>/virtualenv.py
```